# Updating rows in DataTable - why isn't this working?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm trying to update fields in a DataTable. The field I'm trying to edit is a date, I need to format it.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string originalRow = row["Departure Date"].ToString();   //displays "01/01/2010 12:00:00 AM"
    row["Departure Date"] = DateTime.Parse(row["Departure Date"].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string newRow = row["Departure Date"].ToString();   //also displays "01/01/2010 12:00:00 AM"
}
```

How come this isn't getting updated?

Comment: Are any of those Departure Dates NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column is a DateTime column.

The column stores DateTime values and is unaware of formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It's being stored internally as a DateTime, and you're not changing that, in fact the code above is completely redundant because your setting the value (`DateTime`) as the `DateTime` you've just parsed, which was a `DateTime` originally.  You need to store it as a string.